# Using Auth:User() in Laravel 5.2 view for nav

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have an index route "/" that loads index.blade.php which extends the master. I'm unable to use Auth::User() in the nav bar which is a partial included from the master. It does work on pages that require authentication. I have Login and Register buttons that link the AuthController via /login and /register and would like those to be replaced by Logout when a authenticated user is viewing the "/" index page or any other page where authentication is not required.

When a user logs in, the are redirected the the /dashboard route which works correctly and the nav bar shows correctly, but when they go an view the homepage, the login and register buttons are in the nav and clicking on them just redirects them back to the "/" index route, not showing a login or register form. (since they're already logged in i'm assuming.) The only way to get a form again is by manually entering /logout in the address bar.

I've trying looking up answers all over the place but can't figure it out.

`dd(\Auth::user())` returns null in the controller.
I've seen a lot of similar questions but having to do with older versions of Laravel but the solutions don't seem to work or I'm just not applying them correctly.

Thanks for the help!

route.php

```
Route::get('/','PagesController@index');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
        //    
        Route::controllers([
         'register' => 'Auth\AuthController',
         'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
        ]);
});
```

PagesController.php

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    //

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //

    }

    public function index()
    {

        $nav_active = 'home';

        return view('pages.index',compact('nav_active'));
```

app.blade.php

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      @if (Auth::guest())
        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
      @else
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
             {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     @endif
</ul>
```

page/index.blade.app

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put everything inside the `web` middleware. The `web` middleware consists of other middlewares that handles your sessions. No session = no user.

For example, one of them is called `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession`, which is responsible for starting your session.

I'm not sure why you decided to put that particular route outside the `web` group, but without it, you won't have a user. You should only put routes outside the group if you plan on doing other things, such as building an API.

Comment: It's from inexperience with Laravel. I haven't been using it very long. For some reason I thought that when routes were in the `web` middleware group, It required authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You have a backslash before your Auth::user() in your dd(). Also could you replace Auth::guest() with Auth::check() in your app.blade.php?

Comment: Auth::check() results in `Trying to get property of non-object` from within app.blade.php. I was reading that the session isn't available yet when the view is called. The login, register and my protected pages use middleware and they work. it's the pages that don't use it that don't.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In configured my navbar:

```
@if(Auth::guest())
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
     <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
@else
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
     <i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                               <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>            
@endif
```

But when I login, this navbar give me error:

***FatalErrorException in AliasLoader.php line 63:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!***

To resolv this enter in the **bootstrap/autoload.php** and add the following line at the end of the file:

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 120);
```